# What does alt-` do in Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently noticed an unusual behavior:  When I press alt-` (that's the backtick), my Chrome windows seem to minimize (or restore, if pressed a second time).  This happens regardless of which program I'm currently using -- so if I open Word and press alt-`, I can see Chrome appearing or disappearing in the background.  I'm using Windows 7.

Is this a documented behavior?  What is actually happening?

**Update**:  I just found this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90422) which documents the behavior, but I'm still curious whether anyone knows of possible uses for the "feature."

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this bug. **Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1** and **Google Chrome v16.0.912.63m**.